# Why can I add but not remove a Dim statement in debug mode?

Tags: excel, vba, variables, declare

A bit of a trivial question, but it got my interest.

I often edit my code on the fly, or in other words, when in debug mode. I do this so I can quickly check the edits I have made for performance.

When in debug mode, one can neither remove nor alter `Dim` statements without countering the warning message:

> This action will reset your project, proceed anyway?

I assume this is due to the compiler having stored variables in the memory in a manner specific to their data types, something which presumably can't be altered while the code is 'running'.

I have noticed, however, that *adding* a declaration in break mode can be done without any issues. Trying to remove or edit this line then once again throws the warning message.

Why is it possible to add but not to remove/edit declarations in break mode?

Comment: This happens when you try to remove the `_ ` line breaks or a `with` happens with lots of things, sometimes even when trying to delete a blank line...

Comment: I am aware, but that's not quite related to my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I strongly assume that the VBA runtime prevents you from modifying *existing* entries in the symbol table. Consider you have done something like

```
Dim i as Integer
i = 3
Debug.print i
```

You set a breakpoint to the `Print`-statement and change the type of i to `String` - what should the runtime do with the content of `i`? Implicitly convert it to a String? And what should happen if a conversion is not possible?

Adding a new entry into the symbol table doesn't do any harm because it doesn't modify anything that was done previously, so the runtime allows you to do so.

Btw: If you remove `Option Explicit` (I know you & me never do this...) and assign a value to an (undeclared) variable: This variable is now put into the symbol table and if you try to add a `Dim`-statement now, you will get the `This action will reset...`-message.

Comment: Even if I break before I populate the `i` variable, the project will be reset if I try to remove or alter the declaration. In such a case, no content is present and therefore no mishaps can occur between the variable type and true content type

Comment: In fact, `i` has a value (0). I think the point is that there is an entry in the symbol table (name/type/value) , and in that moment the runtime prevents that you modify it.

Comment: Makes sense. Cheers for the thoughts on this

Comment: Fyi See also [@MathieuGuindon stating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56710015/constant-expression-required-error-on-function-declaration-line/56710335#56710335) **Dim** and Const statements *aren't executable*, they're declarative statements - you can't place a breakpoint on them: when the compiler sees a Const declaration when it processes the VBA code, it evaluates the value expression in **static context**, at ►*compile-time* and **"burns"** the value into all call sites.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that if you open a Workbook that declares even a single Public Function in its project with the 'Notify Before State Loss' VBE option enabled, VBE will prompt you with the "This action will reset your project, proceed anyway?" message as soon as you attempt altering the declaration line of this function. Probably because Excel somehow "loads" a variable that will hold the returned value...