# "constant expression required" error on function declaration line

Tags: excel, vba

I have a function written in Visual Basic, which is supposed to read in two Excel workbooks and to some textual analysis on them.

The issue that I am getting is that whenever I try to run the function in a cell in my sheet, I get the error "constant expression required" in VBA and the "#VALUE!" error in the cell.

My function line looks like

```
Function CriticalPercentage() As Double
```

and I call the function by typing "=CriticalPercentage()" in the cell.

When I click enter after typing my function call in the cell it goes to VBA, shows the error message, and `Function CriticalPercentage() As Double`
 is highlighted in yellow. It also highlights in blue the `.Count` in the very last line of the following code that I have provided from my function.

```
Function CriticalPercentage() As Double

    Debug.Print "the first line works fine"

   ByVal WorkbookName1 As String, ByVal WorkbookName2 As String

' this section accesses the excel files and sheets the script will be working with

    WorkbookName1 = "name of excel file"
    WorkbookName2 = "name of excel file"

    Workbooks.Open WorkbookName1
    Workbooks.Open WorkbookName2

    ' define variables for the the two workbooks
    Dim Workbook1, Workbook2 As Excel.Workbook
    Dim Worksheet1, Worksheet2 As Excel.Worksheet

    ' create workbook objects to work with
    Set Workbook1 = Excel.Workbooks(WorkbookName1)
    Set Workbook2 = Excel.Workbooks(WorkbookName2)

    ' sets worksheet variables to the sheets contained in the two workbooks, respectively
    Set Worksheet1 = Workbook1.Sheets(1).Select
    Set Worksheet2 = Workbook2.Sheets(1).Select

'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

' this section of code works on reading in all the neccessary info from the ARCHER excel file

    ' search for [Application Name & Finding] 
    Dim i, j, k As Integer
    Dim numRows As Integer
    Const numRows = Worksheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count
```

I have tried putting a `Debug.Print` statement right after `Function CriticalPercentage() As Double` but it does not show up in the immediate window, so I am led to believe that I am doing something wrong in the declaheration of the function.

I would appreciate any help on this and any insight as to why I am getting this error. if further code needs to be provided I will gladly do so.

Thanks so much!

Comment: You can't declare a constant like that. You already have `Dim numRows As Integer` (btw that really should be `As Long`). Get rid of the `Const`.

Comment: No need to `Select` either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem isn't with the function's signature, the problem is with this instruction:

```
Const numRows = Worksheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count
```

`Dim` and `Const` statements aren't executable, they're *declarative statements* - you can't place a breakpoint on them: when the compiler sees a `Const` declaration when it processes the VBA code, it evaluates the value expression *in static context, at compile-time* and "burns" the value into all call sites.

```
Const foo = 42
Debug.Print foo
```

Once compiled is essentially:

```
Debug.Print 42
```

At compile time, `Worksheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count` isn't a constant expression: it requires objects that won't exist until run-time, like the `UsedRange` reference.

So long story short, use `Dim` for variables, and keep `Const` for things that are *constant* - like `rgbRed = &HFF0000`, or `Pi = 3.14159`, i.e. things that are always going to have the same value, regardless of how or when you look at it. If it's not constant, it shouldn't be a `Const`.

Comment: Thanks for the really detailed and clear answer! I removed `Const` from `numRows` and changed its type to `Long`, as one of the comments on my post suggested. Yet I still get the exact same error message and the exact same sections of the code highlighted as I specified in my post. Is it possible at all that this error is being caused from something later on in my code? Or the way I'm reading in the Excel sheets?

Comment: Did you remove the `.Select` calls? BigBen's comments should be heeded as well =)

Comment: Yes I did, my bad forgot to mention. I actually fixed the third line of the code I provide in my post and made it `Dim WorkbookName1, WorkbookName2 As String` which I think fixed the error on the original line of code that had blue highlight, but now the next line of code which is `Dim AppNameStrings(Worksheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count) As String` has a blue highlight on `.Count`, but I am not sure why.

Comment: Ah, ok got it - as I wrote above, `Dim` statements aren't executable, so their content must be evaluatable at compile time. Change `Dim` to `ReDim`, and if you want a `Dim` statement for that array you can do `Dim AppNameStrings() As String` to declare it as a dynamic array.

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks so much for helping me I'd been stuck on that error for too long, really appreciate it :)